# Does anyone have experience making Festival voices and recording their own prompts?

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, scripts

One of my acquaintances on a forum recently posted a list of things to check off and I decided, since I have a virtual machine with audio input and output, to give this a shot.

The first thing I did was read the checklist provided.

Then I wrote a little tutorial after a friend of mine helped me figure out how to build and install each of these components.

After that was done, I downloaded a series of voices and balanced prompts from the arctic databases. I extracted some of the voices and did a

```
~/festival/festival$ make test
```

and got an introduction message, followed by this message:

```
voice script status: FAILED
test modes (script)
text modes
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : voice_cmu_us_rms_cg
festival: text modes, caught error and tidying up
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
modes script status: FAILED
test parse (script)
parse script completed
parse script status: CORRECT
test scherr (script)
scherr script completed
10c10
Festival Speech Synthesis System 2.5.0:current February 2017
Festival Speech Synthesis System 2.4:beta December 2014
14c14
clustergen_engine: Copyright (C) Carnegie Mellon University 2005-2017
clustergen_engine: Copyright (C) Carnegie Mellon University 2005-2014
scherr script status: INCORRECT
```

Here's the post I'm talking about: http://forum.audiogames.net/viewtopic.php?pid=339244#p339244

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install festival? It looks like it was installed one sub-directory too deep. ie normally `~/festival/festival` should only be `~/festival`.

Comment: cd ~/festival $ ls
Arctic_passage.txt                  cmu_us_rms_arctic-0.95-release.zip  festvox
cmu_us_awb_arctic-0.95-release.zip  cmu_us_slt_arctic-0.95-release.zip  festvox_kallpc16k.tar.gz
cmu_us_bdl_arctic-0.95-release.zip  festival                            festvox_rablpc16k.tar.gz
cmu_us_clb_arctic-0.95-release.zip  festlex_CMU.tar.gz                  flite
cmu_us_jmk_arctic-0.95-release.zip  festlex_OALD.tar.gz                 speech_tools
cmu_us_ksp_arctic-0.95-release.zip  festlex_POSLEX.tar.gz               SPTK-3.10

Comment: I thought I needed to tar everything in ~/festival so it wouldn't extract into the home directory
When I git clone --recursive into festvox and the respective tools, it creates a folder for speech_tools, festival, SPTK, Festvox, which has no target for make install, and Flite. Those are the five directories inside the one I created called festival.

Comment: I updated this a little bit. Evidently, the documentation says to create the environment variables at /home/user/projects/ In my case, /home/myname/festival/ although I could rename that.

Comment: I updated this and according to the documentation, they set their environment variables to /home/theirname/projects/ in my case, /home/myname/festival/
So, export ESTDIR=/home/myname/festival/speech_tools